# How do i configure a Kubernetes Replication Controller to ensure there is a replica on each worker node/minion?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to configure an RC such that i have a single replica on each of my worker nodes?

I just created a x2 replica RC for elasticsearch and it has placed both instances onto just one of my worker nodes. I would prefer to have one instance on each of my worker nodes.

This is particularity important for an application like elasticsearch that would use persistent storage on the docker host - having two elasticsearch instances using the same datastore would likely cause issues.

How is this possible to achieve?

---

Environment:

```
1x Kubernetes master - physical server running CoreOS
2x Kubernetes nodes - physical servers running CoreOS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't choose nodes directly for pods created by scaling up a replication controller. The scheduler assigns nodes based on constraints. You can artificially prevent pods from going to the same node by making them use a resource a node only has one of, like a hostPort.

The daemon controller proposal (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/13368) sounds more like what you want, which would let you spread pods across nodes

Comment: Thanks for your response Jordan. Are you able to elaborate more on how to artificially constrain a node based on resource availability?


And how would it tolerate an entire node going down? would the RC be prevented from bringing up the instance on the remaining node with this configuration? thanks!

Comment: If you assign a hostPort to your ES pods then the scheduler knows it can only put one replica per node.  If one of those nodes goes down, the RC will try to create a new pod to replace it, but that pod won't schedule unless there are other nodes without ES.

Comment: thanks Tim and Jordan. I added "hostPort": 9200 and "hostPort": 9300 to my replication controller definition for elasticsearch. It behaves as you described: for example if i was to schedule 3 replicas for my 2-node-cluster, a replica goes onto each node and the 3rd replica gets stuck in a pending state. So by just scheduling the same number of replicas as nodes it ensures that each node gets replica each.